# Javascript subtracting fine, adding fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have a webpage made of a lot of PHP and Jquery/javascript

I have a function that runs when a submit button is clicked

```
$("#yesterday").click(function(){
            var $date = $.datepicker.parseDate('yymmdd','<?php echo $_POST['date']; ?>');
            var julDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yyoo',new Date($date));
            Number(julDate);
            julDate = julDate - 1;
            String(julDate);
            var $date = $.datepicker.parseDate('yyoo',julDate);
            var julDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yymmdd',new Date($date));
            var $longDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('DD MM d, yy',new Date($date));
            $("#date").val(julDate);
            $("#longdate").val($longDate);
            $("#orwell_btn").click();
return false;
});
```

This function works PERFECTLY it reduces the date by 1 and reloads the page and executes my SQL query returnning all the correct info

if I change the fifth line and make the function liek so:

```
    $("#tomorrow").click(function(){
            var $date = $.datepicker.parseDate('yymmdd','<?php echo $_POST['date']; ?>');
            var julDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yyoo',new Date($date));
            Number(julDate);
            julDate = julDate + 1;
            String(julDate);
            var $date = $.datepicker.parseDate('yyoo',julDate);
            var julDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yymmdd',new Date($date));
            var $longDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('DD MM d, yy',new Date($date));
            $("#date").val(julDate);
            $("#longdate").val($longDate);
            $("#orwell_btn").click();
return false;
});
```

the function doesn't complete and my page loads but as if it would on the very first load (which I have logic to handle but it should be advancing by 1 day ie doing the opposite of the yesterday button)

seems very odd to me

Comment: I have also tried removing the `$("#orwell_btn").click();` line and replacing it with `alert(julDate);` and it doesn't show an alert box if I modify the tomorrow button function to -1 again it works the same as the yesterday button it just seems to be the addition its failing on

Comment: What does + 1 do exactly?  + 1 second or + 1 day?

Comment: wow nice mistake rookie...should have noticed I was calling a function to no where

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 it adds + 1 to the days becuase I convert the date to yy (ie 2012) and the day of the year to 3 digits like 2012072

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Number(julDate)` returns a number with the parsed value.
It doesn't actually change anything.

Therefore, `julDate + 1` is string concatenation.

You want `julDate = Number(julDate)`.

Answer (score 4):

`Number(julDate);` doesn't do anything to `julDate` AFAIK.  Perhaps you mean  `julDate = Number(julDate);`?

Comment: that makes a sense, so why does the - work, does it automatically convert strings to numbers with a - symbol?

Comment: @ScottC: Yes.  Welcome to the wonderful world of Javascript type coercion.

Comment: Similarly, `+x` will automatically coerce to a number.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple typing problem. Your `julDate` is still a String when you add/subtract the 1 (as `Number(` will return a value - that you never assign - but not convert the passed variable). When you subtract the type is converted to a number as a `-` can only be performed on a numeric value. Yet, `+` can also be used to concatenate strings and will therefore treat your variable like a String.

See this fiddle for clarification: http://jsfiddle.net/wRbwX/1/

All you need to do is convert your string to a number (by doing `parseInt` for example) and it should be working

Answer (score 1):

That's because

string - int -> tries to parse string as int, then subtract

string + int -> Convert int to string, then appends. So, if you have "3" as month, you end up with "31"

Answer (score 0):

change to :

```
julDate = Number(julDate);
julDate =julDate +1;
```